# Before AsyncTask all execute I change fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Before AsyncTask all execute I change fragment
I created an application with two fragments. In one fragment I use AsyncTask. When I execute this I and change fastly fragments I got that application has been stopped.

This is code of fragment 1 using AsyncTask:

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

    EditText fragment1_edit_text;
    Button fragment1_plus_button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container,savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        fragment1_edit_text = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment1EditText);
        fragment1_plus_button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment1PlusButton);

        fragment1_plus_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    String link = "http://to.ly/api.php?longurl=";
                    String address = fragment1_edit_text.getText().toString();
                    link += address;
                    new getResult().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,link);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    public class getResult extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String result = "fail";
        String link = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            return GetSomething(link);
        }

        final String GetSomething(String address)
        {
            try {
                link = address;
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream response = url.openStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
                result = reader.readLine();
                reader.close();     
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){    
            addLink(new Link(link.substring(29)+":", result));      
        }   
    }

    DatabaseHelper helper;

    private void addLink(Link link){

        if(link.get_short_link().contains("http://to.ly/")){
            helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);  
            RuntimeExceptionDao<Link, Integer> linkDao = helper.getLinkRuntimeExceptionDao();
            linkDao.create(link);
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Link has been added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error, try change URL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And this is selecting fragment

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(position == 0)
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment_1);
        else
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment_2);
        ft.commit();

        drawer_list.setItemChecked(position, true);
        if(position == 0)
            setTitle("Fragment 1");
        else
            setTitle("Fragment 2");

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(drawer_list);
    }
```

Please forgive me gaps in my knowledge, I am newbie.

Is it possible to fix this?

And I get this:

`01-14 07:29:38.335: D/AndroidRuntime(1813): Shutting down VM
01-14 07:29:38.335: D/AndroidRuntime(1813): --------- beginning of crash
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813): Process: pl.nominalista.fragmentator, PID: 1813
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at pl.nominalista.fragmentator.Fragment1.addLink(Fragment1.java:101)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at pl.nominalista.fragmentator.Fragment1.access$0(Fragment1.java:91)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at pl.nominalista.fragmentator.Fragment1$getResult.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:81)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at pl.nominalista.fragmentator.Fragment1$getResult.onPostExecute(Fragment1.java:1)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
01-14 07:29:38.335: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel async task onPause() handler. Look on fragment life time cycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Override fragment's onPause() method, and cancel the asynctask.

Declare the asynctask globally as follows.

```
getResult asyntask;
```

When you call the asynctask call as follows.

```
asyntask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,link);


@Override
public void onPause() {
     asyntask.cancel(true);
}
```

and in doInBackground() method, keep checking for cancellation.

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String link = params[0];
        if (isCancelled()) break;
        return GetSomething(link);
    }
```

Comment: `@Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String link = params[0];
   if (isCancelled()){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
   }
   return GetSomething(link);
  }`
I added your code, only change this part above and I stil get error that application has been stopped when I use AsyncTask and fastly change fragment

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: I left old part of code and now it's working or I'm to slow to get error ;)

Comment: I stil have error.But when I should pause asynctask? Maybe in creating new fragment view, but I can't pass data between fragments.